# Fail to split downloaded txt file

Tags: android

I have a String that I try to split. The following code works

```
lsSagor = "some text\n Some more text\n More text~Text again\n Text\n text~Some text ..."

final String[] laList = lsSagor.split("~");

String[] laSaga = laList[0].split("\n");
```

Gives:

```
laSaga[0] => some text

laSaga[1] => some more text

laSaga[2] => More text
```

But if I download the textfile, it fails to split and gives:

```
laSaga[0] => "some text\n Some more text\n More text"
```

So it seems the first split works, but not the second.

Here is the code I use to download the file

```
String lsSagor = getFileFromUrl(BASEURL+"/sagor.txt");

public static String getFileFromUrl(String url) 
{
    InputStream content = null;
    try 
    {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Execute HTTP Get Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //handle the exception !
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content), 4096);
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();


}
```

Comment: You created the text file in one os and then uploaded to another (seems between windows and linux variant). So, line breaks were converted. :)

Comment: The previous commenter may be right. By the way, in your getFileFromURL function, you read lines from the file, then merge them into a string and then you want to split it again... it's a bit weird.

Comment: @Sarwar: was thinking of the same problem...

Comment: It is Linux from desktop to server to Andriod. Android uses \n for newline right? The split on newline is the second split, thats why I first put i together and then split again. Also, that code was something I found, nothing I wrote myself.

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

I don't think you will find your string contains any newline character to split on, you would need to do

```
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
       }
```

to get that and I'm sure there is an easier way to just read it newlines and all in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the problem is in String.split() function
Old method but work :)

```
    public static String[] splitString(String str, char separator)
{
    String[] retVal = null;

    int length = str.length();
    int size = 1;

    int jIndx = 0;
    int expressionLength = 0;

    while ((jIndx = str.indexOf(separator, jIndx + 1)) != -1)
    {
        size++;
    }

    retVal = new String[size];
    jIndx = 0;

    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray() ;
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if (charArray[index] == separator)
        {
            retVal[jIndx] = str.substring(index - expressionLength, index);
            jIndx++;
            expressionLength = 0;
        }
        else
            expressionLength++;


        if (index + 1 == length)
        {
            retVal[jIndx] = str.substring(index + 1 - expressionLength, index + 1);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the (not so beautiful) solution

```
lsSagor = "some text# Some more text# More text~Text again\n Text# text~Some text ..."

String lsSagor = getFileFromUrl(BASEURL+"/sagor.txt");

 final String[] laList = lsSagor.split("~");

    giAntalSagor = laList.length;

    String[] laSaga = laList[0].split("#");

    final String[] guiLaList = new String[giAntalSagor];
    for (int i = 0; i < giAntalSagor; i++)
    {
        guiLaList[i] = laList[i].replaceAll("#", "\n");
    }
```

guiLaList is used for layout with "\n" and the other list laList to get the information I wanted.